# What's wrong with my use of json_decode?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a simple form with buttons and i am using jQuery and an ajax call to save.php. The dataType is set to json.

In save.php i use 
`$selections= json_encode($_POST['selections']);`

The $selections are stored in a mysql column selections (which i thinks is in JSON format)

`[{"arrA":["a1","a3","a5","a8"]},{"arrB":["a1","a8"]},{"arrC":["a1"]}]`

Now in show.php i like to parse the arrays and i manage to do this with

`$test = json_decode($row['selections']);
echo 'Array A: '.$test[0]->arrA[0]. ' |'.$test[0]->arrA[1]. ' |'.$test[0]->arrA[2]. ' |'.$test[0]->arrA[3].'<br/>';`

I have the feeling i am doing something wrong, do you see it?

regards

Comment: It really helps if you specify what is the problem. If you get an error, then describe it. If you get output that doesn't match your expectation, then show the output and show expected output.

Comment: Is this a spot the error quiz? Are you having any actual trouble?

Comment: *One* thing you are doing wrong is not using `implode` like this: `echo 'Array A: '.implode(' |', $test[0]->arrA).'<br/>'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what your problem is, but try using

```
$test = json_decode($row['selections'], true);
```

Comment: tx daniel, that's what i was missing